# What was Karna's Nagastra?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, weapon, karna, naga

In the [Mahabharat](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m08/m08090.htm) there is an incident between the final encounter of *Arjuna* and *Karna* where *Karna* used his *Nagastra* against *Arjuna.*

> **The Suta's son then fixed on his bow-string that foe-killing, exceedingly keen, snake-mouthed, blazing, and fierce shaft, which had been polished according to rule**, and which he had long kept for the sake of Partha's destruction.

Here it is written that *Karna* made that weapon for killing *Arjuna*. But in previous verses it is written that the weapon was actually a snake *Ashwasen* who entered *Karna's* quiver.

> Thinking that that was the time for gratifying his animosity towards, as he thought, the wicked-souled Partha, **he(Ashwasen) quickly entered into Karna's quiver, O king, in the form of an arrow.**

If *Ashwasen* was the arrow where was that arrow prepared by *Karna* to kill *Arjuna*.